# How to remove Microsoft Address OOB Email Signature from Outgoing Emails in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, outgoing-email

Environment: SharePoint 2016, Configured with SMTP

My user receives email alerts from my SharePoint Server 2016, like below.

Email signature contains ***Microsoft Corporation | One Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052-6399*** which is misleading. How do I remove it ?

[image]

I checked the resource files, and couldnt find out exactly where this address is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the email text is held within

```
 C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\1033\FPEXT.MSG
```

The location may vary depending what version of SharePoint you are on.

Please note that making any changes to out of the box features or items is not recommended and that any changes you do make may be overwritten during any upgrades or feature releases.